# Linking Azure Dev Ops with GitHub - Replace ADO Repo with GitHub Repo

Tags: github, azure-devops, git-branch, pull-request

Is it possible in Azure Dev Ops (ADO) to do the below?

1. Link ADO Repo to GitHub Repo.
2. When we create branch in ADO, it is actually creating branch in GitHub Repo and not in ADO Repo.
3. When we create Pull Request in ADO Repo, it will be a Pull Request against branch in GitHub Repo not in ADO Repo.

Comment: Not without a ton of custom integration that's likely to be very janky and break constantly. What is the issue with just using GitHub?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your reply. Just curious, as Azure Dev Ops Pull Request review is more user friendly than Github. For example, it shows mini scroll bar to indicate area of changes in the codes.